# convert millisecond with decimal into millisecond

Tags: java, actionscript, midi

In Midi timing, I have calculated to convert MIDI time to millisecond but contains decimal numbers (e.g. 2000.5454545454). To reduce the loss of precision, what is the best solution to convert into millisecond without the decimal so that the Actionscript can time accurately? Math.Round?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.Round is a fine option. If this is a running total and you want to avoid cumulative errors you should keep the running total un-rounded and just pass the rounded value to whatever you're doing in Actionscript. That way you'll never be more than a millisecond off.

Comment: Likewise, 1 millisecond won't make so much difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
trace(Math.Round(2000.54545454));
```

Comment: The _trace_ will show you the number in the output window, it's only there for debugging.

Comment: but why do I need to multiply by 1000?

Comment: sorry, is 2000 the number of seconds or milliseconds? If it's seconds and you want to convert it to milliseconds you need to multiply by 1000. If 2000 is the number of milliseconds you don't need to multiply.

Comment: 2000 is the millisecond as stated in my question.